# LWJGL Texture a cube

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, cube

I'm currently rendering a cube with VBOs, and with color. I want to drop some texture on them, and I don't have any idea about it. Still learning OGL, but how can I render the cube with texture on them? I need another VBO for texture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need another FloatBuffer, not to mention a texture.
When mapping a texture onto an object, you need to use texture coordinates ([How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work)). Use `glTexCoordPointer()` to map your texture onto the cube.
You can load textures with the slick library that comes with LWJGL.