# implementing mesh with opengl

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm currently trying to implement mesh using opengl and i've read a lot of stuff online and on textbooks but I wanted a more intuitive explanation on stackoverflow.

From what I understand, to model shapes with polygonal meshes, you need the vertices(x,y,z coordinates), normal vectors, and texture coordinates(?). I guess my question is what are texture coordinates? They are often referred as uv. I sort of understand that you need vertices and normal vector but i'm not sure what texture coordinates are.

In addition, is mesh a process in which it simply takes points and covers those points with polygons?

Comment: A mesh is a collection of vertices (a vertex is an x,y,z and other information - for lighting you might add a normal, nx, ny, nz and if you're texturing a texture coordinate u, v - if you're multi-texturing 2 or more of them) *and* often also a collection of indices, which index the vertices into triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

related question already answered on stackOverflow.

[How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work)

There are some good conceptual explanations on there.