# How do you turn a mesh into a model with libGDX?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, libgdx

so, I have created a mesh consisting of 2 triangles into my game. Now I want to turn this mesh into a model so it can be rendered with the ModelBatch. If I just render it seperatly it gives me weird depth issues with the models:

[image: Example]

If I render multiple different models together it does not give me the error (The two kinds of trees). So If i render it as a model the problem will hopefully go away.

Answer (score 1):

To use a `mesh` in the `modelBatch` as you said, you have to pass it in a `model`. To do so you have to create a `mesh` with the desired vertices and indices.

**Vertices**  : are the points which compose your 3D/2D shape (here it's your plane compose by two triangle).

**Indices** : the order of the vertices that must be triangulated, indicies must be "redundant" to close and triangulate the path.

For example here is an image to better explanation :

[image]

Then you must specify attributes of position, uv and normals. Attributes are used to give information to shader (`mesh` must be rendered with a shader). For every vertex  the shader has the information given by those attributes.

**Position** : are 3D points of the vertices in space.

**UV** : are used for texture mapping and are mendatory (more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532670/16296442)).

**Normals** : are normalized vectors, the normals of face or vertex (in your case I would assume it's only pointing to the north pole for every vertices).

To create your `mesh` :

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, vertices.length, indices.length,
                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE),
                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal, 3, ShaderProgram.NORMAL_ATTRIBUTE));

mesh.setVertices(vertices);
mesh.setIndices(indices);
```

Mesh require boolean if the mesh will be dynamic or not, vertices length, indices length and some vertexAttributes which give attributes to the shader. Default shader of `model` are using `ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE`, `ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE` & `ShaderProgram.NORMAL_ATTRIBUTE` which you may tune for using your own shaders.

Then you add the vertices and the indices. For your case `vertices` and `indices` are :

```
float vertices[] = {-1, -1, 0, // bottom left corner
                          -1,  1, 0, // top left corner
                           1,  1, 0, // top right corner
                           1, -1, 0}; // bottom right corner
    
short indices[] = {0,1,2, // first triangle (bottom left - top left - top right)
                         0,2,3}; // second triangle (bottom left - top right - bottom right)
```

After creating your mesh you need to give it to the `modelBuilder` as following

```
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(); // creates model build
modelBuilder.begin();// begin it
        
modelBuilder.part("plane", mesh, 
                GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,  
                0, 
                mesh.getNumIndices(), 
                new Material()); // creates your mesh
        
model = modelBuilder.end(); // makes the model
instance = new ModelInstance(model);

//...
//render it in render loop
modelBatch.begin(camera);
modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
modelBatch.end();
```

Following mainly :

- tutorial from [blog.xoppa.com](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/basic-3d-using-libgdx/)
- documentation on [modelBuilder](https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/3d/modelbuilder-meshbuilder-and-meshpartbuilder)

Hope it will help you and others that are in search for the same process.