# texture is flipped and upside down

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to draw a simple texture on top of simple square .

However, the texture image is seen flipped and Upside down . I think I have all the texture definitions correct so I have no idea what's the problem .

here is my texture loading code :

```
final int[] textureObjectIds = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1 , textureObjectIds , 0);
        if (textureObjectIds[0] == 0){
            Logger.Log( TAG , "Unable to generate new texture object");
        }

        //define options for decoding
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inScaled = true ;



        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources() , resourceId , options); //decode texture resource to bitmap
        if (bitmap == null){
            Logger.Log(TAG, "Resource ID " + resourceId + " Could not be decoded");
            GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1 , textureObjectIds , 0);
            return 0;
        }

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjectIds[0]); //bind texture to our texture object

        // define magnify and minimize filters
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D , GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D , GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

        //GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D , GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        //GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D , GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T , GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0); // load bitmap data to texture

        bitmap.recycle(); // release recycle

        GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0); //unbind from the texture

        return textureObjectIds[0];
```

Coordinates of my square and texture :

```
private static final float TEXTURE_FLOOR  = 0.0f;
private static final float TEXTURE_CEIL= 2.0f;

private static final float[] VERTEX_DATA  = {
                                                                        //Coordinates : X , Y , Z , S , T
                                                                        //Triangle1
                                                                        -0.5f , -0.5f   , 0.0f , TEXTURE_FLOOR , TEXTURE_CEIL  ,
                                                                         0.5f , -0.5f   , 0.0f , TEXTURE_CEIL  , TEXTURE_CEIL ,
                                                                        -0.5f ,  0.5f   , 0.0f , TEXTURE_FLOOR , TEXTURE_FLOOR ,

                                                                        //Triangle2
                                                                         0.5f  , -0.5f  , 0.0f , TEXTURE_CEIL , TEXTURE_CEIL ,
                                                                         0.5f  ,  0.5f  , 0.0f , TEXTURE_CEIL  , TEXTURE_FLOOR ,
                                                                        -0.5f  ,  0.5f  , 0.0f , TEXTURE_FLOOR  , TEXTURE_FLOOR
                                                                      };
```

More info from the code :

```
private static final int     POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT               = 3 ;
private static final int     TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT    = 2 ;
private static final int     STRIDE                                 =  (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT)
                                                                        * BYTES_PER_FLOAT ;

vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(0 , textureShaderProgram.getPositionAttributeLocation() , POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT , STRIDE);
vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, textureShaderProgram.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(), TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
```

where :

```
public void setVertexAttribPointer(int dataOffset , int attributeLocation , int componentCount , int stride){
    floatBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeLocation, componentCount, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, floatBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeLocation);
    floatBuffer.position(0);
```

example image of my problem with a waze icon : 
[image: waze]

Comment: Why are your texture coordinates in the range of 0 to 2? For what you are trying to achieve, they should be in the range of 0 to 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work

Comment: The image does not look like texture coordinates from [0,2]. More like [-0.5,0.5]. Can you show the `glVertexAttribPointer` for the texture coordinates? For me this looks as if you would be using the 0th and 1st element of the array instead of the 4th and 5th.

Comment: @Reigertje I changed the texture coords to the range of 0-1 and -0.5-0.5 , but I get the same result

Comment: @BDL added the relevant code take a look

Comment: You do not use your dataOffset for the texture coordinates. So you use your vertex data as texture coordinates. The upper `floatBuffer.position(0);` should probably be `floatBuffer.position(dataOffset);`

Comment: @Reigertje correct ! thanks ! my image is whole like it should be. but sadly now the image is simply flipped upside down . any suggestions ?

Comment: I would suggest flipping the texture coordinates, replacing every ceil with floor and vice versa for the t component. Please refer to the link I posted earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work  as to how texture coordinates work.

Comment: No problem. I posted it as an answer, so you can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your texture coordinates are off. Please refer to [How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work) as to how texture coordinates work, and set them properly.

Besides that, you forget to use the `dataOffset` argument in your `setVertexAttribPointer` function.

```
public void setVertexAttribPointer(int dataOffset , int attributeLocation , int componentCount , int stride) {
  floatBuffer.position(0);
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeLocation, componentCount, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, floatBuffer);
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeLocation);
  floatBuffer.position(0);
}
```

Causing your vertex position values to be used for the texture coordinates. You should set your floatBuffer to start at the first texture coordinate, which is the `dataOffset`.

```
public void setVertexAttribPointer(int dataOffset , int attributeLocation , int componentCount , int stride) {
    floatBuffer.position(dataOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeLocation, componentCount, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, floatBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeLocation);
    floatBuffer.position(0);
}
```