# Draw more Image using texture(Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, wear-os

Hi guys am new to andorid openGl.
I drawm an image using texture and shader ,

Now my question is it possible to draw more images using the same texture or we need to have more texture ?

Comment: Please, be more specific

Comment: Is it possible to draw more bitmap image using a sing texture @webo80

Comment: Like, one half for one image, and the other half for another, for example?

Comment: yes exactly but i need to draw 4 images , first half 2 image and next half 2 image, do u have any example  @webo80

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this blog post](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/) as reference, and, when applying textures via coordinates, do it with four parts

Comment: Need to draw in andorid wear, could you help me to draw , i already saw this tutorial and bit confusing .. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007529/draw-an-image-based-texture-in-opengl-androidwear?rq=1