# OpenGL / Cocos2d-x What's difference between v_texCoord vs gl_FragCoord in shader?

Tags: opengl, shader, cocos2d-x

I've seen the shader code using these two. But i don't understand what's difference between them, between texture and fragment.

As i know, fragment is pixels, so what's texture?

Some use these code:

```
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / rectSize.xy;
vec4 bkg_color = texture2D(CC_Texture0, uv);
```

some use:

```
vec4 bkg_color = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord);
```

with `v_texCoord = a_texCoord;`
Both works, except the first way displays inverted image.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example 'v_texCoord' looks like a pre-calculated texture coordinate that is passed to the Fragment Shader as a Vertex Attribute, versus the 'uv' coordinate calculated within the Fragment Shader of the first example.

You can base texture coordinates off whatever you like - so long as you give the texture2D sampler normalised coordinates - its all about your use case and what you want to display from a texture.

Perhaps there is such a use-case difference here, which is why they give different visual outputs.

For more information about how texture coordinates work I recommend this question's answer: [How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work)