# gaussian blur in webgl error

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, fragment-shader, gaussianblur

I am trying to write a simple gaussian blur shader in webgl. i have searched a lot about this and i think i understand the idea behind it.
given this **3X3** kernel .how can i apply it to my vertex shader?

[Here is my current output](https://jsbin.com/nuvenotoqe/edit?html,js,output)

```
[ 0.0625  0.125  0.0625 ]
[ 0.125   0.25   0.125  ]
[ 0.0625  0.125  0.0625 ]
```

in particular how to get the neighbouring pixels?

does this logic even make sense?

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vUV;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;

void main(){
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(????,????)*0.0625;


}
```

what should i put in vec2() above? say if i want to get top left texture value for the kernel.
suppose vUv was **(20,20)** to get **(19,19)** should i write

```
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV  +  vec2(vUV.x-1.0,vUV.y-1.0))*0.0625;
     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(vUV.x,vUV.y-1.0))*0.125;    
     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(vUV.x+1.0,vUV.y-1.0))*0.0625;

     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV  +  vec2(vUV.x-1.0,vUV.y))*0.125;
     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(vUV.x,vUV.y))*0.25; 
     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(vUV.x+1.0,vUV.y))*0.125;    


     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV  +  vec2(vUV.x-1.0,vUV.y+1.0))*0.0625;
     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(vUV.x,vUV.y+1.0))*0.125;    
     gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(vUV.x+1.0,vUV.y+1.0))*0.0625;
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 how can i do that? here is my current output https://jsbin.com/nuvenotoqe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Rabbid76 also the implementation here dosent seem to be dividing with anything? https://github.com/phoboslab/WebGLImageFilter/blob/master/webgl-image-filter.js

Comment: @Rabbid76 can you explain this a little bit in the answer as i am very new to webgl

Comment: Rabbid76 linked to webglfundamentals in their answer so I thought I'd add [this article implements a blur](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html).

Comment: @gman thankyou so much, i will surely go through that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The texture coordinates which are used to look up the texture by `texture2D`, have to be in range [0.0, 1.0].

See also

- [How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work)
- [WebGL Fundamentals, WebGL 3D - Textures](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html).

To make your shader work, you have to define a uniform variable, which contains the offset to the texel which you use to create the blur effect:

```
uniform vec2 offs_blur;
```

Use this offset for the 9 texture lookups:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(-offs_blur.x, -offs_blur.y))*0.0625;
gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(         0.0, -offs_blur.y))*0.125;  
gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2( offs_blur.x, -offs_blur.y))*0.0625;

gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(-offs_blur.x,          0.0))*0.125;
gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(         0.0,          0.0))*0.25;   
gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2( offs_blur.x,          0.0))*0.125;  


gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(-offs_blur.x, offs_blur.y))*0.0625;
gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(         0.0, offs_blur.y))*0.125;   
gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2( offs_blur.x, offs_blur.y))*0.0625;
```

The offset to the neighbour texel is the reciprocal of the texture size *(1/width, 1/height)*.
But the offset don't need to be the exact offset, to the neighbour texel, to gain a blur effect.
The blur effect will increase if you increase the offset. Of course this will cause a loss of quality. With increasing offset, artifacts and banding effects will grow up. To avoid this you would have to increase the number of texels which you look up (e.g. look up 5x5 texels)

Set the uniform like this:

```
offs_blur = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"offs_blur");

var blur = 20.0;
gl.uniform2fv(offs_blur,[blur/image.width, blur/image.height]);
```

See the example, which applies the suggestions in the answer to the  original code of you question:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
 canvas.width = window.innerWidth
 canvas.height = window.innerHeight
 document.body.appendChild(canvas)
 

 var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl')
 //  clear canvas with any color you want
 gl.clearColor(0.75, 0.85, 0.8, 1.0)
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)


 function main() {
   var image = new Image();
     image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

   image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/GdkFHnw.jpg";
   image.onload = function() {
  render(image);
   }
 }

 // generic function to create shaders
 function createShader(gl, source, type){
  var shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  console.error('ERROR compiling shader type=>'+ type, gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  return;
   }
 return shader
 }


 function createBuffer(data) {
   data = data instanceof Float32Array ? data : new Float32Array(data);
   var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,data,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
   return buffer;
 }


 // function that returns a `program` from compiled vertex & fragment shaders
 function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
   var program = gl.createProgram();
   gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
   gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
   gl.linkProgram(program);
   var success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
   if (!success) {
    // something went wrong with the link
    throw ("program filed to link:" + gl.getProgramInfoLog (program));
   }
   return program;
 };

  var texture_width = 1, texture_height = 1; 

 // Creates a texture from an existing canvas or HTMLImage (new Image())
 // without needing width & height or with a typed array (Uint8Array) that has
 // a specified width & height
 // e.g.
 // createTexture(HTMLImageElement) will work just fine
 // createTexture(Uint8Array,width,height), remember that a texture needs four values for one pixel
 function createTexture(image,width,height) {
   
    var texture = gl.createTexture();
   
   // Set the active texture slot to 0
   // WebGL has ~30 texture slots, meaning you could have about 30 textures bound at once
   // Think of it as an array of 30 pointers to texture objects that you can set
   gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0); // Sets the current 'index'
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,texture); // binds the selected texture object to the current pointer
   
   // How to filter the texture when it needs resizing when sampled
   // (Is it going to be blurred when streched?)
   // (gl.NEAREST means no blur)
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
   
   // What to do if UV coordinates go outside the texture's size
   // gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE repeats the pixel at the texture's border.
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   
   width === undefined && height === undefined ?
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,image):
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,width,height,0,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,image);

   return texture;
 }


 function render(image){
  //alert('rendering...')
 //vertex shader source

 const vertexShaderSource = [  
   'attribute vec2 aPosition;',
   'attribute vec2 aUV;',
   'varying vec2 vUV;',
   'void main(){',
   '  gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);',
   '  vUV = aUV;',
   '}',
 ].join("\n");


 //fragment shader source
 const fragShaderSource = `

   precision mediump float;
   varying vec2 vUV;
   uniform sampler2D uTexture;
   void main(){
   float brightness = 1.1;

   gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vUV);
   gl_FragColor.rgb *= brightness;

   }`


 const blurShader = `

 precision mediump float;
 varying vec2 vUV;

 uniform sampler2D uTexture;
  uniform vec2 offs_blur;

 //[ 0.0625  0.125  0.0625 ]
 //[ 0.125   0.25   0.125  ]
 //[ 0.0625  0.125  0.0625 ]
 void main(){
  
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(-offs_blur.x, -offs_blur.y))*0.0625;
   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(         0.0, -offs_blur.y))*0.125; 
   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2( offs_blur.x, -offs_blur.y))*0.0625;
   
   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(-offs_blur.x,          0.0))*0.125;
   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(         0.0,          0.0))*0.25; 
   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2( offs_blur.x,          0.0))*0.125; 


   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(-offs_blur.x, offs_blur.y))*0.0625;
   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2(         0.0, offs_blur.y))*0.125; 
   gl_FragColor += texture2D(uTexture, vUV + vec2( offs_blur.x, offs_blur.y))*0.0625; 
 }
 `
 // const fragShaderSource =  [
 //     'precision highp float;',
 //     'varying vec2 vUV;',
 //     'uniform sampler2D texture;',
 //     '',
 //     'void main(void) {',
 //     'vec4 c = texture2D(texture, vUV);',
 //     'gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0 - c.r, 1.0 - c.g, 1.0 - c.b, c.a);',
 //     '}'
 // ].join('\n');
 //create vertex shader
 var vertexShader = createShader(gl, vertexShaderSource, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

 //create fragment shader
 var fragShader = createShader(gl, blurShader, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

 //create program
 var program = createProgram(gl,vertexShader, fragShader);

 // get location of attributes & uniforms
 aPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"aPosition");
 aUV = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"aUV");
 uTexture = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uTexture");
  offs_blur = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"offs_blur");
  

 var buffer = createBuffer([
   // X  Y     U   V
    0.5, 0.5,  1.0,0.0,
   -0.5, 0.5,  0.0,0.0,
    0.5,-0.5,  1.0,1.0,
    
    0.5,-0.5,  1.0,1.0,
   -0.5, 0.5,  0.0,0.0,
   -0.5,-0.5,  0.0,1.0,
 ]);

  texture = createTexture(image);

  // Setup GL State
 gl.useProgram(program); 
 gl.uniform1i(uTexture,0);
  var blur = 20.0;
  gl.uniform2fv(offs_blur,[blur/image.width, blur/image.height]);

  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,texture);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);

 // These functions tell WebGL how to interpret the vertexbuffer data

 // Every sixteen bytes, use the first eight (4 bytes is a float) for the 'aPosition' attribute
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(aPosition,2,gl.FLOAT,gl.FALSE,16,0);

 // Every sixteen bytes, use the last eight bytes for the 'aUV' attribute
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(aUV,2,gl.FLOAT,gl.FALSE,16,8);

 // These need to be enabled or the vertex data isn't fed indo the vertex shader
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aUV);

  window.onresize = resize;
  resize();
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function draw(delteMS){

 gl.clearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0,6);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function resize() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
}

main();
```

Comment: thankyou so much .it will take some time for me to digest everything