# textureLod() returns 0 where texelFetch() returns 1

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I have a shader in glsl that is using a 3D texture to create some shading effects.

I am currently using texelFetch() but now need to use interpolated LOD levels to achieve the final effect.

The texture is declared like this:

```
uniform layout(binding=0) sampler3D diffuse_map;
```

And then I sample it like this using texelfetch():

```
vec4 val = texelFetch(normal_map, ivec3(((r)*0.5/cube_dim+vec3(0.5))*(voxel_resolution-1)),0);
```

The above works.

I then try to sample the same texture with textureLod as follows:

```
vec4 val = textureLod(normal_map, ivec3(((r)*0.5/cube_dim+vec3(0.5))*(voxel_resolution-1)),0);
```

I am guessing this fails because the coordinate system is different for textureLod, but then, what is the range for the coordinate for this function?

The [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureLod.xhtml) does not explicitly state it, and soemtimes the coordinate system is that of the texture, soemtimes is 0 to 1 and soemtimes it's -1 to 1

Comment: The texture coordinates are in range [0, 1]. See [How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work)

Comment: They are not when using imageLoad/store nor texelFetch though

Comment: Your question was about `textureLod`. Of course `texelFetch` uses pixel coordinates. But that is all well documented.

Comment: @Makogan: "*and soemtimes the coordinate system is that of the texture, soemtimes is 0 to 1 and soemtimes it's -1 to 1*" I don't know any function which accesses textures that take normalized *signed* values like that, where -1 maps to the left side and 1 to the right. You can use mirrored repeating sampling to create the effect of that, but that's not part of a texture accessing function.