# vTextCoord value is not working - c# OPENTK

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk, vertex-shader

My app is displaying an image in full screen by using OpenGL shader code as shown below. The vertex shader I used here is copied from somewhere. Can anyone explain why here used `vTexCoord = (a_position.xy+1)/2;`? When I'm trying with `vTexCoord = a_position.xy`, my OpenGL output is split into four rectangles and only it's top right portion is showing the image. Other three sides are seem as blurred. What change should I do to work it with `vTexCoord = a_position.xy` ?

Some important functions used in the project are shown below. Please check and help to correct.

```
float[] vertices = {
            // Left bottom triangle
            -1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, 1f, 0f,
            // Right top triangle
            1f, 1f, 0f,
           -1f, 1f, 0f,
           -1f, -1f, 0f
    };
    private void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                    varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                                    void main() {
                                    vTexCoord = (a_position.xy+1)/2;
                                    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1);
                                    }");
        GL.CompileShader(vertShader);

        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture;varying vec2 vTexCoord;                      
          void main ()
         {
        vec4 color= texture2D (sTexture, vTexCoord);                           
        gl_FragColor =color;
                             }");
        GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
    }
    private void InitBuffers()
    {
        buffer = GL.GenBuffer();
        positionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        positionLocation1 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture");
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
    }
 public void DrawImage(int image)
    {
        GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        //GL.Ortho(0, 1920, 0, 1080, 0, 1);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation1, 0);
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
        GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(1920, 0, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
        GL.Vertex3(1920, 1080, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 1080, 0);
        GL.End();


        RunShaders();
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.PopMatrix();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PopMatrix();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        glControl1.SwapBuffers();
    }
    private void RunShaders()
    {
        GL.UseProgram(program);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / 3);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why here used `vTexCoord = (a_position.xy+1)/2;`?

The vertex coordinates in you example are in range [-1, 1], for the x and  component. This matches to the normalized device space. The normalized device space is a cube from the left-lower-front (-1, -1, -1), to the right-top-back (1, 1, 1), this is the area wich is "visible". This area is mapped to the viewport.
This causes that the vertex coordinates, in your example, form a rectangle, which covers the entire viewport.

If the texture coordinates should wrap the entire texture to the quad, then the texture coordinates (u, v) have to be in range [0, 1]. (0, 0) is the lower left of the texture and (1, 1) the upper right.
See also [How do OpenGL texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work)

So the x and y component of `a_position` have to be mapped form the range [-1, 1], to the range [0, 1], to be used as uv coordinates for the texture lookup:

```
u = (a_position.x + 1) / 2
v = (a_position.y + 1) / 2
```

---

> What change should I do to work it with `vTexCoord = a_position.xy`?

This is not possible, but you can generate a separate texture coordinate attribute, which is common:

```c
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texture;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    vTexCoord   = a_texture;
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1);
}
```

```cs
float[] vertices = {
  // x    y   z      u   v
    // Left bottom triangle
    -1f, -1f, 0f,    0f, 0f
     1f, -1f, 0f,    1f, 0f
     1f,  1f, 0f,    1f, 1f
    // Right top triangle
     1f,  1f, 0f,    1f, 1f
    -1f,  1f, 0f,    0f, 1f
    -1f, -1f, 0f     0f, 0f
};
```

```cs
buffer = GL.GenBuffer();
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buffer);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

positionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
tetureLocation   = GL.GetAttribLocation(program, "a_texture");

GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(tetureLocation);

int stride   = sizeof(float) * 5; // 5 because of (x, y, z, u, v)
int offsetUV = sizeof(float) * 3; // 3 because the u and v coordinates are the 4th and 5th coordinate

GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, stride, 0);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(tetureLocation,   2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, stride, (IntPtr)(offsetUV));
```