# Can't bind a texture to a GL_QUADS

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut, opengl-compat

I try to do an animation in OpenGL, my vertices and animations are working, but I would like to put a background image to it, with a file such as a bmp, or whatever.

So after a few reads I try the quads technique, which is simply to show a quad and bind a texture to it.

I use the STB_Image library, and it seems that I correctly point to my file (if I make mistakes on the filename I definitely got a much faster response from my program).

And I implemented a print to see if it catches the right file and it does!

My code look like this, and my result is a white square that appears in the correct coordinates, but no texture appears, the file is correctly loaded (with correct sizes printed), it just doesn't bind or appear on the square...

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

int width, height, nrChannels;
unsigned char* data = stbi_load("test.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data == NULL) {
    printf("Error in loading the image\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Loaded image with a width of %dpx, a height of %dpx and %d channels\n", width, height, nrChannels);
unsigned int texture;

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(2.0, 1.0);
glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(8.0, 1.0);
glTexCoord2f(8.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(8.0, 7.0);
glTexCoord2f(8.0, 7.0);
glVertex2f(2.0, 7.0);
glTexCoord2f(2.0, 7.0);
glEnd();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you setting the texture data *after* drawing the quad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) specify the two-dimensional texture image for the texture object. You have to do that the quad is drawn.
Furthermore 2 dimensional texturing has to be enabled by `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.
The texture coordinates have to be in range [0.0, 1.0] (See [How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work)).
[`glTexCoord2f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml) has to be set before [`glVertex2f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml), because the current color, normal and texture coordinates are associated with the vertex when `glVertex` is called.
Since you don't generate mipmaps ([`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)), the texture minifying function ([`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)) has to be set to `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_NEAREST`. Else the texture would be mipmap incomplete.

```cpp
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

```cpp
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(2.0, 1.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(8.0, 1.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(8.0, 7.0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(2.0, 7.0);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! It works ! I will take a complete lecture about texture coordinates, thanks again !