# Texturing 3d polygons in OpenGL with C++

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, polygon, opengl-compat

I'm new to OpenGL and programming in general and I'm trying to paste any picture on all surfaces of a cube and a pyramid  so the picture can move with them and rotate with them 
I tried a lot of tutorials but most of them  focus on 2d or with other programming languages like C# .
how can I make texturing to my polygons

Comment: *"but most of them focus on 2d"* - you have to wrap 2d textures around the 3d mesh. Put different parts of a 2d texture on the faces of the 3d mesh. Note, 3d textures contain [Voxel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) that's somthing completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] but most of them focus on 2d [...]

You have to wrap 2d textures around the 3d mesh. Put different parts of a 2d texture on the faces of the 3d mesh. Each face of the 3d object is 2 dimensional. You have to define the texture coordinate attributes for each vertex of a face (respectively primitive), to *select* an area of the 2d texture, to display on the primitive.
See also [How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work).

Note, 3d textures contain [Voxels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) that's something completely different.